# Dispose() is not called for View

Tags: xamarin, view, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, dispose

In a viewpager, i have added a view in 10 pages. My requirement is need to dispose unused view contents (ie) currently 1 view is displayed in viewpager and need to dispose unused 9 views contents. So i have override the Dispose() as like below.

```
  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        DisposeContent();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

But, the dispose() is not being called, when navigates to next page.

Can you please help me out how to dispose the unused view contents?

Answer (score 2):

Dispose would only get called when you pop a page, when u move from one page to another, a forward navigation, the page is still alive and would be available in the navigation stack. When a page is removed (when performing back navigation) the page will get disposed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried by removing the view in button chart. Then also, the Dispose() not called.

Comment: when you pop a ContentView (Navigation.PopAsync()), it would return the popped view, then you can explicitly call the Dispose, this would ensure dispose is always called.